# HTML/JSP Wrong Input and Wrong output

Tags: html, forms, jsp

In JSP file, there is a column(xpaths), 
I think I enter(and I want to) this:

`"/breakfast_menu/food/name[text()="Belgian Waffles"]"`

but it turns out like this:

```
/breakfast_menu/food/name[text()="Belgian Waffles”]
```

And when I get this parameter in doPost
Using this code:

```
String xpaths = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("xpaths"),"UTF-8");
```

I get this:

```
/breakfast_menu/food/name[text()="Belgian Wafflesâ]
```

What is wrong with my code? How can I fix this?

EDIT:
Here is my JSP file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <form method="post" action="/ServletSuite/servlet/XPathServlet">
        URL: <input type="text" name="URL">
        XPaths: <input type="text" name="xpaths"><br>
        *separate multiple XPaths with ';'<br>
        <input type="submit" name="send">
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should post the real code. But obviously what's happening is a curly quote is turning into a nonsense character. But where did the curly quote come from?

Comment: @developerwjk I add my jsp file code..Can you find something wrong?

Comment: This is probably just like you said, bad input. Are you typing your input in Word before pasting it into the form?  Word and similar applications will cause your quotes to transform to curly quotes.

Comment: You also do not need URLDecoder.decode around getParameter.  getParameter already does that.

Comment: @developerwjk I type this in the input field. Ironically, if I type somewhere else and I paste then It will not have this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of all possible curly quotes and do `xpaths = xpaths.replaceAll("”", "\"");` for each type.